# Pass quoted value sql plus param

Tags: sql, bash, shell, sqlplus

I have a shell script script.sh, and a sql script modify_database.sql

In script.sh, I launch the sql script with some param using :

```
sqlplus user/password ... @modify_database.sql « param_id » « param_newValue »
```

And in the sql script, I get the parameters value with :

```
UPDATE T_TEST SET C1 = &param_newValue WHERE ID = &param_id
```

But I have a lot of problem with the « param_newValue » parameter.
In fact, this parameter could contain some spaces, slash, single quote and double quote character.
For example : **L’avion du pilote était surnommé le « Redoutable »**

I have a bunch of values to update.
Each new values are stored in a txt file, like that :

```
id;value
1; L’avion du pilote était surnommé le « Redoutable »
2; Another example of a « test » that’s it
```

How can I do to pass this param to sqlplus and set the value like that ? The quoted part is giving me a hard time :/

EDIT :

Example, in the input file I have : 
123;;;"aaaa/vvvv/COD_039/fff=Avion d'office";"aaaa/vvvv/COD_039/fff=Hello d'orien";

I get this line, I do a cut command to get the first column (ID), the 4th column (to replace), and the 5th column (replacement).

I have a XML node, with a node which contain the 4th column text, and need to replace by the 5th column content.

So I do :

```
sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASSWORD@$DBHOST:$DBPORT/$DBSCHEMA @majConfXML.sql "$id" "$newcode"

update T_TEST set XML = updatexml(xmltype(XML_CONF),
'//A[@name="XXX"]//B[@name="YYY"]//pkValue','&2').getClobVal()
```

But in the param, there is some quotes.
So when I do the update request with '&2', the request is running but it does not work properly.
How can I escape/pass the param value into the updateXML request ?

Thank you

Comment: Where does the parameter value come from? Do you just want this hard coded string the way you posted it with all the unicode quotes?

Comment: The value come from a txt file, with on each line : id;another example of a possible « test » value’s

Comment: If you can read your value from a file into a variable `myvalue`, then you can pass it safely with `"$myvalue"` whether or not it contains quotes

Comment: Yes but, when I pass it to sqlplus, and load it into the update request, the quotes are going to be misanterpreted...

Comment: Can you copy-paste the command you run and the error you get from sqlplus in that case? Please ensure the paste is complete and correct.

Comment: I don’t have the code with me but I can write a simple faulty example tomorrow. But It’s easy to see there will be a problème. There is quote in the value, and we pass it with : update ... xx = ‘&1’ . The quote in param value had to be « protected » in some way, or « escaped », but I don’t know how do that properly.

Comment: I edited my original post, it's a bit more complicated, I try to explain the most simple I can, but it seems like you need some details ;)

Comment: If you need to escape the outputs, write each `"` that you wish to preserve as `\"`.

Comment: What do you need to put in the variable in order for it to insert correctly? For example, does it work the way you want if you replace `'` with `''`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find a problem in my bash script before the sqlplus call.
In fact, it was xargs command which I use who interpret simple quote. I simply add double quotes around each string with slash and quote in my input file.

Next, before calling sqlplus, I replace all “ ‘ “ (quote) by “ ‘’ “ (quote quote)